# Use toString method with format string to convert double variable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Use the ToString method with a format string to convert the double variable, pi to the string variable, `s`, in scientific point format and 3 digits of precision.

This is what I have so far

```
s = pi.ToString("F3")
```

My answer is wrong.

I am given this feedback:

> Given an initial value of 3.14159 for pi, you assigned 3.142E+000 (instead of 3.1416) to s

I was expecting the output to be 3.142.

If somebody could help me please, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: For scientific format use `E3` format. `3.14159.ToString("E3")` will output `3.142E+000`

Comment: It should return 3.142 but then you said the scientific notation should be E3 so I don't know what to put. I already used 4 attempts and this is my last attempt.

Comment: and what is `s = pi.ToString("F3")` returning?

Comment: I am sorry. I might sound stupid but I have no idea I am doing this question on myprogramming lab. I am really new to visual basic language. myprogramming lab does not show any output and my professor is not helpful that is why I am here.

Comment: If you don't know what output should be - how you expect we can help you?

Comment: As I mentioned before that myprogramming lab does not provide an output and I am new to this language.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double pi = 3.141;
    string sPi = pi.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(sPi);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Does it fit to your needs? If now, which version of .net are you using?

Comment: Visual basic. I need a single statement

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
string.Format("{0:E3}",pi);
```

Comment: oh okay then. why is the question tagged as c#?

Comment: I have no idea. I am new here

Answer (score 0):

may be you need all the pieces

```
Sub Main()
    Dim s As String
    Dim pi As Double

    pi = Math.PI
    s = pi.ToString("F3")
End Sub
```

or the single

```
s = Math.PI.ToString("F3")
```

Comment: I am not sure so the last question was Use the ToString method with a format string to convert the double variable , pi to the string variable , s, in fixed point format and 4 digits of precision.

Comment: and the answer was s = pi.ToString("F4"). so I think it should be in this format but I am not sure

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: but your question says _"3 digits of precision"_

Comment: So was all that to kid people here?

Comment: no I really needed help and I was doing it myself too. Isn't it a good thing that I figured it out myself. I did say thanks to you guys for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys I figured out the correct answer its
s = 3.142.ToString("e3")